# draw view: the drawing is not in the same position as my finger or my cursor

Tags: swift

I created a view where we can draw, but when i draw, the line is create very below to the cursor or finger.

The red line is the movement of my finger or the cursor and the black line is what is drawn

[image]

```
   class DrawViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
        var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
        var swiped = false

        override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
            swiped = false
            if let touch = touches.first {
                lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
            }
        }

        func drawLines(fromPoint:CGPoint,toPoint:CGPoint) {

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
            imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
            context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

            context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
            context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
            context?.setLineWidth(5.0)
            context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)

            context?.strokePath()

            imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }

        override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
            swiped = true
            if let touch = touches.first {
                let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
                drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
                lastPoint = currentPoint
            }
        }

        override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){ if !swiped { drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint) } }

        override func viewDidLoad() {super.viewDidLoad()}
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}
```

Answer (score 0):

try change you imageView temp for

```
imageView.image?.draw(in: view.bounds)
```

and:

```
context.move(to: fromPoint)
context.addLine(to: toPoint)
```

good luck

Comment: Hello, when i put **context** i have a error when i build: _Value of optional type 'CGContext?' not unwrapped_, i just add a **?**. And the changes do not solve the problem.